# Use Solid State Input Module for Output?

Tags: solid-state-relay

Below is a diagram of an "industrial" input module or also referred to as a signal conditional relay. Although it is dubbed an input module. Is there any reason I couldn't put a load between terminal 3 and terminal 4?  The load is a small device which draws approximately 200 mA.  My thought is that the DC power supply input Plus (+) of the device would be tied to Vcc and the power DC common (-) of the device to terminal 4.  Without a voltage on the field input (the off state), the logic output would be Vcc... so the device would not be powered since device's DC and DC common would be at the same voltage.  Unfortunately, the manufacturer does not supply the leakage current.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this device is intended to feed the input of a PLC or similar device, the output transistor is unlikely to be rated to handle 200 mA - but you'd have to read a detailed datasheet to be sure.  I'd expect it to be designed to handle 10 - 20 mA.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. The spec sheet says 100mA. Other than the current limitation, would it be feasible?

Comment: I suppose it would work, if you stay within the specs - but a plain optocoupler would be much cheaper.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Yes, but I have these on hand :-)